# How to copy specific columns from one table to another in Tarantool

Tags: database-migration, tarantool

I have 2 tables, for example:

```
table X, columns:
 A integer
 B string
 C number

table X2, columns:
 A integer
 C number
```

how to copy contents of `X` to `X2` (excluding the missing columns) in Tarantool?

tried, but didn't work:

- `INSERT INTO "X2" SELECT "A", "C" FROM "X"`
- `SELECT "A", "C" INTO "X2" FROM "X"`

(version used: 2.6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error do you get? I don't have 2.6.2 at hand, but when I try on 2.7.0 everything works just fine:

```
tarantool> \set language sql
tarantool> \set delimiter ;
tarantool> CREATE TABLE x (col1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col2 VARCHAR(20), col3 INTEGER);
tarantool> CREATE TABLE x2 (col1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col2 INTEGER);
tarantool> INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, 'a', 10), (2, 'b', 20), (3, 'c', 30);

tarantool> SELECT * FROM x;
---
- metadata:
  - name: COL1
    type: integer
  - name: COL2
    type: string
  - name: COL3
    type: integer
  rows:
  - [1, 'a', 10]
  - [2, 'b', 20]
  - [3, 'c', 30]
...

tarantool> SELECT * FROM x2;
---
- metadata:
  - name: COL1
    type: integer
  - name: COL2
    type: integer
  rows: []
...

tarantool> INSERT INTO x2 SELECT col1, col3 FROM x;

tarantool> SELECT * FROM x2;
---
- metadata:
  - name: COL1
    type: integer
  - name: COL2
    type: integer
  rows:
  - [1, 10]
  - [2, 20]
  - [3, 30]
...
```

Comment: weirdly your code snippet works '__') last time i tried it was showing "unknown column 'a'"

Comment: Be aware that when you enclose a column name in quotes, you have to put it in uppercase. For example, `select "col1" from x` will give `Can’t resolve field 'col1'`, while `select "COL1" from x` will work as expected.